# How to "chain" two seperate observables in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am developing a web application with Angular2 and I have got some problems with getting data from the server.

```
 import ...

 @Component({
 ...

 })
 export class EmployeeManagementTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

private employees: Employee[];
private departments: SelectItem[] = [];
private selectedDepartment: string;
private columns: any[];
private paramSub: any;
private employeesSub: any;
private departmentSub: any;


constructor(private employeeManagementService: EmployeeManagementService, 
            private route: ActivatedRoute, 
            private router: Router,
            private ccs: ComponentCommunicatorService,
            private logger: Logger) { }

ngOnInit(){

    this.columns = [
     ...
    ];

    //ccs is just a service for storing/getting app wide infomation

    this.selectedDepartment = this.ccs.getSelectedDepartment();
    this.getDepartments();
    this.getEmployees(this.selectedDepartment);

    ...
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    /*this.employeesSub.unsubscribe();
    this.departmentDub.unsubscribe();*/
}

getDepartments(){

    this.departments.push({label: 'Alle', value: 'all'});

    this.departmentSub = this.employeeManagementService.getDepartments().subscribe(
          data =>  {data.forEach((item, index) => {
                        this.departments.push({label: item, value: index.toString()});
                    });    
                   },
          err => this.logger.error(err),
          () => {this.logger.log('done loading');
                 this.departmentSub.unsubscribe()}
    );
}
getEmployees(department: any){

this.employeesSub = this.employeeManagementService.getEmployees(department).subscribe(
          data => {this.employees = data},
          err => this.logger.error(err),
          () => {this.logger.log('done loading');
                 this.employeesSub.unsubscribe()}
    );
}
```

As you see when the component gets initalized it calls two Methods for getting data. The methods get observables from my service and subscribe to them.
The problem is that order is like `call1, call2, result1, result2, ...` and I think there is something not right. It should be `call1, result1, call2, result2, ...` or am I wrong? I tried subscribing to observable2 in the `onComplete` of observable1 but I think dedicated methods would be useless then.
I have researched and found some solutions with subscribing to both observables simultaneously with concat but I just want the code to continue after getDepartments() when all data traffic is finished.

And should I unsubscribe in the `OnDestroy()` or in the `OnComplete` of the `subscribe` function I don't really get the difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to control the execution order of observables, you need to build an asynchronous data flow leveraging operators like `flatMap` (execution in series) or `Observable.forkJoin` (execution in parallel)

Here are samples:

```
// Series
someObservable.flatMap(result1 => {
  return someOtherObservable;
}).subscribe(result2 => {
  (...)
  (...)
});

// Parallel
Observable.forkJoin([ someObservable, someOtherObservable ])
  .subscribe(results => {
    let result1 = results[0];
    let result2 = results[1];
  });
```

Comment: As I understood `forkJoin` it would give me my employees and departments in one observable. But I want my two methods to stay independent from each other. Is that also possible?  Maps are also a thing I do not understand. What is `flatMap` doing exactly? I tried looking it up but I still don't get the purpose of the `map`'s.

Comment: They will be executed in parallel but yes within the same asynchronous data flow. You can implement your processing into two different methods. The only restriction is that they return both an observable...

Comment: The different between `map` and `flatMap` is that the first one returns raw objects whereas the second one observable that can take part of the data flow. This video could help you to understand and see the difference in action: https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-rxjs-map-vs-flatmap ;-)

Comment: That with two different methods is what I already did or isn't it? Sorry webdevelopment is still very new for me.

Comment: No problem! Yes, it would be: Observable.forkJoin([ this.getDepartments(),
this.getEmployees(this.selectedDepartment) ]). ... but `getDepartments` and `getEmployees` must return both observables.

Comment: My service is what returns me the observables the methods subscribe to. But how can I implement the subscription thing that it only finishes the method if the observable is fully received? Or should I use Promises instead as observables are not really needed here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120601/discussion-between-moessi774-and-thierry-templier).

Comment: Your answer helped tremendously as I was able to do both... However, the parallel forkJoin example had intended results but seemingly not a good way of actually telling what came through either the array or circumstance... but albeit with the array winning the actual observable order.  So for example, if you put a console.log in each observable it would report back something different that what was in the array order... a little odd to say the least.  Plus the flatMap was a lot less code overall.

Comment: One additional comment... it is easy to see how the forkJoin could allow for multiple observables but what about the flatMap... how would you fold in many different observables.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, such calls are asynchronous, and in consequence, the order of execution and/or arriving results is not deterministic. (Example: When requesting data from API 1 and then from API 2, it might even result in data from API 2 arriving before data from API 1 if API 1 is especially slow or the amount of data is huge.) So, to answer your first question: yes, you are wrong.

When subscribing to the Observable, you probably have some kind of callback function (the place where the data received is used or stored) which is executed by the 1st service once the data arrives. If it is important to trigger the 2nd API call only after receiving the result for the 1st call, this function would be the place to request data from the 2nd service.
Of course, you will not want to couple service 1 and service 2, so a better approach would be to pass a callback function to service 1 which is to be invoked in case of success. Then, your client code can make sure that this callback function requests data from the 2nd service. Of course, there are numerous ways how to handle such cases, and what I described before is just a simple approach.

Regarding the unsubscribing issue: often, it is not desired to unsubscribe when receiving results, as there might be more data coming in afterwards. (This is one of the key differences between Promises and Obvservables). For instance, in an application I am working on, I unsubscribe when “leaving” the component, as I *do* want to keep on subscribing after I received initial data.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. The data service is a apache tomcat with some `jsp` running on it. I am programming with my beginner java knowledge for a few years now. But I do not really understand how I should do/handle the whole callback thing. Could you please explain some more detailed? Sorry I am basically stuck at the basics.

Comment: And with the unsubscribing it is basically the same for me if I unsubscribe in the `OnDestroy` or the `OnComplete` of the observable? Only difference would be if I am still subscribed and server data changes I receive a new observable. Right?